# Are Ideal Greenie 30-192P Ground Wire Nuts approved for use with stranded wire?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, grounding, wire

I looked at page 4 of the UL document here:

http://www.idealindustries.ca/media/pdfs/products/ideal_ul_listed_combinations.pdf

And I notice that it says you can use up to 4 #12 wires. However, it doesn't specify stranded or solid. I assume either and/or both is okay?

My plan is to push through 1 12AWG solid wire from the outlet ground screw through the connector to the box ground screw, then join in 2 12AWG stranded ground wires passing thru the box. Three wires total in the connector This is a 20A receptacle on a 20A breaker in a metal box with EMT conduit.

Comment: Read the header on page 4 

Comment: @Tyson I totally missed that ... Doh!

Answer (score 2):

The deciding factor is whether the device is *listed* (survives UL etc. testing) for that use.  The conventions for listings are as follows.

- If it says "12 AWG", it is listed for both solid and stranded wire.
- If it says "12 AWG SOLID" that means it is not listed for stranded wire.

So, if you have found where it specifies such things, and it is not specific as to solid/stranded, that means both.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tyson pointed out in his comment, this is in the header on page 4 . Combinations of stranded and solid wire are in fact supported.